# Controlling the vertical space of a character in HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts

In the picture below, the 'A' and 'a' are occupying the same vertical space.

Is is possible to change something so the 'a' occupies less vertical space?

I want to get rid of the area circled in green.

[image]

I tried to play with line-height, but in vain.
Also the margin and padding don't have any impact.
Below the HTML:

```
<svg height="800" width="800">
  <text font-size="150px" fill="black" x="30" y="300"
        style="line-height: -10px;">A</text>
  <text font-size="150px" fill="red" x="130" y="300"
        style="line-height: 0em;">a</text>
</svg>
```

Maybe there are fonts that can handle that but I couldn't find any of them.

EDIT: I will integrate this text with a [lasso plugin](https://github.com/skokenes/D3-Lasso-Plugin) and want to avoid that the user selects the character 'a' by mistake by putting the lasso in the zone circled in green.

Comment: You would have to look for a font where the upper and lower case letters have the same height. Or you would need to change the font size of one of the letters

Comment: @Huangism in this case the two latters have the same height. And if I change the font size I will still have the empty space.

Comment: what is the effect you are trying to achieve?  The vertical space will be dictated by the largest line height, which you've given to "A".  You could break up the letters into separate SPANs with the display set to inline-block.  This will give you the ability so set negative margin on the top, essentially raising the position of the "a".

Comment: The space will be there on the lowercase letter no matter what unless your font does not have that space, which is my first point of using a font where upper and lower case letters have the same height... but you can imagine how weird it will look. If you change font size, the space could disappear visually

Comment: @JeffClarke I edited the question to explain why I need to cut the empty space above characters. Also note that each letter is in a different <text> zone in the example I gave.

Comment: Ah... so you are trying to keep the text from being selected when you are using the lasso?

Comment: BTW, you are not using HTML in your code block, but SVG...

Comment: You may be able to trap that glyph for "a" in a separate box with transparent borders and background where the height of that box is lower than the glyph height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see highlighted in blue is the *BoundingBox* of the glyph. Its measure is defined in the font file used by the document (be it HTML, ODT, DOCX or PDF).

Normally the *height* of this BoundingBox is identical for all glyphs of a font (when rendered at a given font size). Only the *widths* of the glyphs do differ (if it is a non-monospaced font). Incidentally, this is also the technical reason why PDFs which use a non-embedded, non-standard font need to still include a `/Widths` array in the `/FontDescriptor` dictionary, but they do not need a `/Heights` array...

You can check this yourself by creating a HTML test page using all letters of the alphabet, upper and lower case, including all digits.

I do not think you can change that with CSS trickery.

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually trying to do ("*[...] want to avoid that the user selects text by mistake [...]*") has pretty much nothing to do with how you're trying to achieve that. In effect, you've asked an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

To prevent text selection in a browser, simple create a CSS class like

```
.notselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

(or do it more sensibly with just `user-select:none` and something that auto-creates the vendor prefixed rules, too).

Then whenever your users start text selecting, slap that class onto the text that they might be drawing over, so that their gestures/mouse activity doesn't result in actual text selection.

Comment: Same comment as in the other answer:   
     
 
Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself clear in the post. In the example, I want the 'a' to be selectable but I don't want the user to select it by mistake when putting the lasso in the zone circled in green.

Comment: then please rephrase your post to make that clearer, bearing in mind that the entire box the `a` is in counts as "the letter". Your eyes may not see it, but to the computer, that white space is *part* of the vector definition for the `a` outline. If you move up `a`, you also move up its associated white space.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am started to think. Maybe there is a font that can fix that but I couldn't find it.

Comment: there isn't. all glyphs in a font have the same minimal glyph height (the height defined by the font's baseline-to-baseline distance), an text spans are set such that any interaction with the "box" the text fits in is text interaction. You could use canvas, but that's about it. The alternative is to not allow "text select" and "lassoo" at the same time.

Comment: I will probably replace the text by pictures, since it is maths formulas I want to manipulate with the lasso. With the pictures I will be able to control the spacing, and also I will have nicer maths display than normal text. I guess it solves the problem in a way...

Comment: if you use a picture, then you've done the exact same as if you've just turned off user selection while lassooing, so I don't see why you would. Just add the user-select:none class on lassoo start, and remove it again on lassoo end, and you'll have done the same thing with less work?

Comment: Sorry I lost you, I want the 'a' to be selectable, but not while lassoing on empty space over the 'a' that is still part of the character. For me creating the picture is equivalent to create my own font that doesn't have glyph height - there is no empty space above and below the characters that are part of the characters.

Comment: you're overloading your terms, though: either a user is selecting text, or they're lassooing. They're not doing both things at the same time. If you want to be able to initiate lassoo while also having the text cursor on top of a letter, simply disallow that instead of trying to fight how every font shaping engine works: by using "a picture" for your letters you're completely removed the notion of text, so there isn't any text to select. So: if you're going to *remove* true text selection entirely, by using pictures, then why not just *disable* text selection instead with less work.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable text selection with CSS.  Make an unselectable class and apply it to text elements where applicable:

```
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Even better to add it at the start of using the lasso, and removing it afterward, such that text selection is possible when not using the lasso.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself clear in the post. In the example, I want the 'a' to be selectable but I don't want the user to select it by mistake when putting the lasso in the zone circled in green.

Comment: That's why I mentioned to add and remove this class at the start end end of lasso.  Text is selectable when you want it to be selectable, and not selectable during the action of drawing the lasso.